# JavaScript exception: "not well-formed" on firefox browser and "XMLHttpRequest.." error on chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, three.js

I am learning three.js. I have converted .obj file to .js file for my object and loaded that object using JSONLoader. It is displaying on Firefox browser. But its showing javascript exception in the console as below:

```
not well-formed Porsche_911_GT2.js:1:1
```

Same code I had run on chrome browser. But there object is not displaying. In the console there are errors as below:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/inwindow/Desktop/webGL/myTHREE.js/obj/car/Porsche_911_GT2.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.     three.min.js:263

THREE.JSONLoader: "obj/car/Porsche_911_GT2.js" seems to be unreachable or the file is empty.                                                three.min.js:262 

 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/inwindow/Desktop/webGL/myTHREE.js/obj/car/Porsche_911_GT2.js'.  three.min.js:263
```

Why this is happening? Can someone help me please?

Comment: You cannot load `file://` urls with xhr, as the first error says. How are you viewing the page on which the object should be loaded?

Comment: @ Bergi: obj/car/Porsche_911_GT2.js : this url i have used in my html page. Object is displaying on firefox but not on the chrome.

Comment: hey I think it requires server to run on both browsers. when I run my page on localhost its showing object on both the browsers and there is no errors and exceptions.

Comment: Yes that is the point @kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your local server relative url of Porsche_911_GT2.js to JSONLoader.
It will not work with file protocol... 
It should be on a server and accessible via http or https protocol.